# Expo BarCodeScanner crashes in some android devices

Tags: react-native, crash, expo, android-camera

I added the Expo BarCodeScanner. On some android devices the app crashes when scanning a code. Is this a known issue maybe? I tested this and on some android devices it works fine but some other android devices the app crashes and restart.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Vibration, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

export default function QrCodeScanScreen ({ navigation }) {

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [voucher, setVoucher] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);


const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
    Vibration.vibrate();
    if (!scanned) {
        setVoucher('');
        scanApi(data);
        setScanned(true);
      } else {
        setData(data);
      }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

const scanApi = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }


if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 35, fontFamily: 'Book' }}>Camera laden...</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 35, fontFamily: 'Book' }}>Geen toegang tot de camera. Ga naar je instellingen om toegang te verlenen.</Text>;
  }

return (
  <BarCodeScanner
   onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
   width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
   height={Dimensions.get('window').height - 100}
  />
);
}
```